# SQL Count the total in a groupby

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

The following shows the top 50 artists based on the number of submissions they have:

**Query:**

```
$artists_most_popular = DB::table('artists')
                        ->join('fanartists', 'artists.id', '=', 'fanartists.artist_id')
                        ->select(DB::raw('artists.*, fanartists.*, COUNT(*) AS total_artists'))
                        ->orderBy('total_artists', 'DESC'))
                        ->groupBy('artists.id')
                        ->take(50)
                        ->get();
```

**View:**

```
    rank | artist | pieces
<?php $i = 1 ?>
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $i }} | {{ $artist->name }} | 0
<?php $i++ ?>
@endforeach
```

How can I make that 0 display the count? For example if the artist showed up on 7 rows, that number would be 7.

Comment: $artist->total_artists doesn't work? If not try to add total_artists field to model.

Comment: $artists_most_popular->->total_artists